# Define symbol as property using lazy initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I have this:

```
export const symbols = {
  toString: Symbol('@xml.js.toString')
};

export class Node {

  [key: string]: any;

  [symbols.toString] = function(){

  };

}
```

but I get this error:

[image]

Which is:

> A computed property name in class property declaration must refer to
>   an expression whose type is a literal type or unique symbol type.

Anyone know what's going on?

If I put it in the constructor, I don't get an error:

[image]

Comment: `key` is `undefined` in your `class Node`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, only unique symbols can be used as computed property names.

As described in [the reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol),

> To enable treating symbols as unique literals a new type unique symbol is available. unique symbol is are subtype of symbol, and are produced only from calling Symbol() or Symbol.for(), or from explicit type annotations. The new type is only allowed on const declarations and readonly static properties, and in order to reference a specific unique symbol, you’ll have to use the typeof operator. Each reference to a unique symbol implies a completely unique identity that’s tied to a given declaration.

Due to listed limitations, object property cannot be unique.

Instead, it can be:

```
export namespace symbols {
  export const toString = Symbol('@xml.js.toString');
};
```

Comment: what is namespace here?

Comment: ^^ answering my own question it's a typescript 1.5 thing

Comment: Yes, the question is specific to TypeScript, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html